# Intent not passing data properly

Tags: android, android-intent

i am a newbie to android development and facing some issue with intents.
I am having a list of items displayed on screen for and want to call a different activity on click of any item in list.

I am using following code for calling a different activity on click of list item -

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View view, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(lv, view, position, id);
        //code to call activity to edit the task
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderModificationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("RowId", id);
        Log.i(TAG, "row clickd --> " + id);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_EDIT);

    }
```

in this above code, I am getting proper id of the list item clicked as 1,2 or 3. For the "ReminderModificationActivity" , I have this piece of code in my onCreate() function-

```
Log.i(TAG, "getIntent --> " + getIntent().getExtras().getInt("RowId") );

        //code to check what row id have been passed
        if(getIntent() != null) {                                        
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();                     
            int mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getInt("RowId") : -1;    
            // Do stuff with the row id here
            if(mRowId != -1){
                //code if RowId valid

            }
        }
```

value received in Log.i is always 0. can anyone please help me regarding what I am missing here ? Please be detailed as i am totally new to this platform.

ans - <strike>int</strike> while capturing intents.

Thanks in Advance,
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use the Intent.putExtra which passes a long value instead of a bundle?

then you just do a

```
intent.putExtra("RowId", id);
```

and retrieve wiht a

```
long incomingID = getLongExtra("RowId", -1);
```

and by the way, try to treat the data as long in both pieces of code

Comment: So i solved it and too silly but I made two mistakes  - 

1. i created a new variable mROWiD  while i was already having one global variable.

`int mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getInt("RowId") : -1;`

2. I needed to use getLong and not getInt. Thanks @Thomas for this.

Thanks guys..!!